# .ejs webpage stuck loading

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, async-await, ejs

I'm learning web development and while following along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi2UwhpooF8&list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH9xx-RRVNG187ETT2ekWFsq&index=38&t=843s) tutorial, the page I'm working on loads indefinitely. I believe it's a problem within my route file but I can't figure out exactly what I did wrong. Could you help point it out to me?

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const photoBasePath = "uploads/photoImages";

const photoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  imageName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tags: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Tag",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Photo", photoSchema);
module.exports.photoBasePath = photoBasePath;
```

Route:

```
const { render } = require("ejs");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const Photo = require("../models/photo");
const Tag = require("../models/tag");
const uploadPath = path.join("public", Photo.photoBasePath);
const imageMimeTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"];
const upload = multer({
  dest: uploadPath,
  fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, imageMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype));
  },
});

//All Photos Route
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("All Photos");
});

//New Photo Route
router.get("/new", async (req, res) => {
  //res.send("New Photo");
  renderNewPage(res, new Photo());
});

//Create Photo Route
router.post("/", upload.single("photo"), async (req, res) => {
  const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null;

  const photo = new Photo({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    imageName: fileName,
    tags: req.body.tags,
  });

  try {
    const newPhoto = await photo.save();
    res.redirect("photos");
  } catch {
    renderNewPage(res, photo, true);
  }
});

async function renderNewPage(res, photo, hasError = false) {
  try {
    const tags = await Tag.find({});
    const params = {
      tags: tags,
      photo: photo,
    };
    const photo = new Photo();
    if (hasError) params.errorMessage = "Error Creating Photo.";
    res.render("photos/new", params);
  } catch {
    renderNewPage(res, photo, true);
  }
}

module.exports = router;
```

View:

```
//=====================================new.ejs===============================================

<h2>New Photo</h2>
<form action="/photos" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <%- include('_form_fields') %>

  <a href="/photos">Cancel</a>
  <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>

//=================================_form_fields.ejs==========================================
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= photo.name %>" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Tags</label>
  <select name="tag">
    <% tags.forEach(tag => { %> <% if (tag.id === photo.tag) { %>
    <option selected label="<%= tag.name %>" value="<%= tag.id %>"></option>
    <%} else {%>
    <option label="<%= tag.name %>" value="<%= tag.id %>"></option>
    <% } %> <% }) %>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Photo</label>
  <input type="file" name="photo" />
</div>

<div>
  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea type="description"> <%= photo.description %> </textarea>
</div>
```

I've tried going through the tutorial back from the start and seeing if I did anything differently and I haven't caught what difference I've introduced into my code. I also made sure check if all my dependencies are installed.

I'm sure it's something obvious staring me right in the face, but I could use another pair of eyes to tell me where I went wrong.I appreciate any help that I could get. Even criticism unrelated to the asked question.

Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In which route you are facing the issue?